# make no accessible area in border less forms

Tags: c#, customization

[image]

this is my customized form by overriding paint event and implemented form features such as moving ,resizing and some new capabilities. i have a problem with this that all of my form area is accessible for example when i set dock property of a control to fill the control will spread on entire form and border will disapear. i wanna to have a separated and not accessible area for border like c# Forms . how can i do it?

tanks for your help

Comment: Creating a custom designer is only a good way to lose a week of your life.  The pragmatic approach is to draw this at design time as well, so it is obvious, or to simply make the window *larger* at runtime by the size of the borders and caption, or to match the sizes that Windows uses and change the border style only at runtime.  Which certainly ought to be your preference.

Comment: It is the wrong approach to override the paint event of your form. You need to paint the non-client area. Take a look at this link: http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=CustomerBorderForm&title=Painting%20NonClient%20Area

Comment: Still it is the wrong approach if you'd like to create a new frame-layout for your form :). If you like your form to behave as a 'normal' window you will have to draw directly in the non client area. Of course you can still add new functionality. Here is another link from the msdn regarding this issue: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb688195%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @user1567896 Thank you for informing me of wrong doing

Comment: @HansPassant also tank you for your help